# Edit or delete question that turned out to be unclear after comments?

Tags: discussion, questions

I've asked a question that included details that were meant to give context but helpful comments show were distracting instead. Shall the question be completely overhauled, removing the context of the comments, or deleted+reposted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Overhaul it. If the current question is hard to answer, anything that makes it easier to answer short of changing the meaning entirely should be done. Make sure your question edits don't invalidate any answers, that's all.

There's pretty much *no* use case for reposting. If you want to repost, the same thing can be aceived by editing/flagging for reopen/bountying/etc (depending on the situation)

Comment: Good point about not invalidating answers

Answer (score 3):

The point of being able to edit your question is so that it can be improved and clarified, so that would seem to be the way to go.

Deleting and reposting seems unnecessary.